# Can you match two cells from a source data using =isnumber(match on excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to return a true/false answer on excel against order numbers as well as line numbers from a source data list.

I am wanting to know if line 41 against order 262050 is in my source data in any row as shown with the highlighted cells in my image.

[image]

My current formula is -

`=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2+D2,Sheet2!B$2:B$1000+Sheet2!D$2:D$1000,0))`

I am regularly updating my source data due to new orders coming in and sales orders being closed as well.

Comment: Use `FILTER()` function instead.

Comment: What do you have on `Sheet2`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. "match two cells" is not clear. Are you combining two cells together via a concatenation and matching them to some other single cell? Are you adding them together for a sum as your formula suggests?

Comment: Note that using `+` adds up the order # and line #, so `10000 + 20` would result in the same as `10010 + 10`. Use `&` instead (and maybe add a character in between, like `ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2&"|"&D2,Sheet2!B$2:B$1000&"|"&Sheet2!D$2:D$1000,0))`

Comment: Try `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(Sheet2!B$2:B$1000=A2)*(Sheet2!D$2:D$1000=D2),0))`.